# 404 error while accessing local file in jsp

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jboss

Below is my project structure. i am using jboss server with eclipse

```
 MyProject
 |_data_folder
         |_data.txt
 |_src
 |_war
```

i have also copied this txt file to server by

```
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="data_folder">
                <include name="**/*.*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
```

the above txt file, i am trying to call in ajax by below code

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/WEB-INF/classes/data.txt", // path to file
    dataType: 'text', // type of file (text, json, xml, etc)
    success: function(data) { // callback for successful completion

    },
    error: function() { // callback if there's an error
      alert("error");
    }
  });
```

But this says 404 error with file not found. What i am missing here. Pease help me on this.

Comment: The `WEB-INF` folder (and anything in it) is by specification **not accessible** via URL. Put your `data.txt` outside of it.